# Rolling updates with Hazelcast

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift, hazelcast

I have a small Hazelcast cluster running inside Openshift 4(kubernetes) in a number of pods. My problem is that when I roll out a new version, sometimes I need to change the configuration of the hazelcast instances in the new version. The problem then arises because the pods and the old cluster is still running, because the new pods aren't started yet properly yet. The new upgraded members will fail because their configurations are incompatible with the running cluster (The old pods). We are using the headless service discovery type described here. https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes. The data in the hazelcast cluster can be deleted between deployments, we have no need to keep anything from the old cluster when we start a new one.

I would like a way to tell the new members and the old members to either ignore their differences, start them up as two seperate clusters that don't find each other, or simply not replicate between the old and new members at all.

I have looked into the portable serialization feature https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.1.2/serialization/implementing-portable-serialization but it strikes me as overkill, as we don't need the cluster data to survive between deployments. I'm also unsure if it will help when we change something in the configuration for the hazelcast instances, which will make the clusters incompatible.

Lastly, I considered changing the deployment strategy for kubernetes so the old pods are killed before the new pods start up, but that will cause downtime for the application when we deploy, which is not great.

Answer (score 1):

Some parts of the Hazelcast configuration cannot be configured at runtime, which means that you won't be able to do the rolling upgrade. In other words, you won't be able to have a cluster with members running with different configurations at the same time.

If the data is not important to you, then you can always use blue/green deployment, meaning that you first start the whole new cluster (with the new configuration), switch to the new cluster, and then stop the old cluster.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there a good way to do that with the headless service discovery method in hazelcast-kubernetes? Any service created for the deployment seems to resolve to the same DNS, at least in our environment, which causes the cluster members to find each other no matter which service i point the hazelcast cluster at.

Comment: No, I think you need to "orchestrate" it on your own. Meaning, that use two different service names and then switch your application from one to another.

Comment: Would you, by chance, know where i can find a description of exactly what parts of the configuration might be incompatible? I have seen the incompatible warning on the joiners and serializers sections but I can't seem to find a page in the manual that lists what parts of the configuration must be identical.

Comment: For sure, you can add new data structures. Check this link: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.1.2/configuration/understanding-configuration.html